# One OnClick handler for multiple buttons in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclick, android-button

I have 3 buttons in a fragment that I want to use the same click event. How can this be achieved within a fragment?

**XML**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:onClick="btnClick_DoSomething"
    android:text="@string/one"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:onClick="btnClick_DoSomething"
    android:text="@string/two"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_3"
    android:onClick="btnClick_DoSomething"
    android:text="@string/three"/>
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public void btnClick_DoSomething(View v) {

}
```

**Error**

`@Override` (within the fragment Java class) becomes underlined in red  and the following error is returned

> Annontations are not allowed here

I want the onClick event to be the same for all 3 buttons

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write @Override annotation as you are not overriding the method. Just use

```
public void btnClick_DoSomething(View v) {


}
```

You will get a callback in this method at runtime.

Comment: I want the onClick event to be the same for all 3 buttons

Comment: Edited my answer. This way you can handle onClick event same for all 3 buttons

Comment: Where does this need to go? `onCreateView` / `onActivityCreated` / somewhere else?

Comment: It is a separate method. Just write it below onCreateView()

Answer (score 0):

What method are you trying to override? Do any of the parent classes have a method `btnClick_DoSomething`? You do not need to override anything when setting a click listener from a Layout XML. Just ensure that a method of the same name with a void return type and a View as its only argument exists in the activity class that will use this layout

The general way to distinguish clicks from different Views in the same onClick handler is to identify them by id

```
public void btnClick_DoSomething(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.btn_1:
               // handle click from button 1
               break;
         case R.id.btn_2:
               // handle click from button 2
               break;
         case R.id.btn_3:
               // handle click from button 3
               break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the onClick event to be the same for all 3 buttons

Comment: @MacaronLover That is how my answer is set up. A click of any of the three buttons will call the btnClick_DoSomething(...) function. Did you want the exact same actions to be taken regardless of what button is pressed? in that case you can remove the switch statement entirely, and just do whatever you need within that btnClick_DoSomething function.

Answer (score 0):

you simply don't do it in XML, do it in Java instead:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:text="@string/one"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_2"
    android:text="@string/two"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_3"
    android:text="@string/three"/>
```

then...

```
private final OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
       switch(view.getId()){
           ... cases...
       }
   }


    somewhere initialising the views you do:
    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_1).setOnClickListener(onClick);
    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_2).setOnClickListener(onClick);
    fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_3).setOnClickListener(onClick);

}
```

Comment: I want the onClick event to be the same for all 3 buttons

Comment: and it is. Just remove the "switch"

Answer (score -1):

There are some misunderstandings here. To override a Click event, your `Fragment` need to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
}
```

Note that the name of the method must be `onCLick`, must return void and recives a `View` as a parameter to be overrided from the interface. In this case you need to set a Listener to each button in your fragment:

```
btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Inside this method you can control which object was clicked by it´s ID

```
 @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
       switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.btn_1:
               // handle click from button 1
               break;
         case R.id.btn_2:
               // handle click from button 2
               break;
         case R.id.btn_3:
               // handle click from button 3
               break;
         }
      }
```

Or, you don't need to override the method, so remove the anotation that will work's fine :

```
   public void btnClick_DoSomething(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.btn_1:
                   // handle click from button 1
                   break;
             case R.id.btn_2:
                   // handle click from button 2
                   break;
             case R.id.btn_3:
                   // handle click from button 3
                   break;
             }
         }
```

Comment: I want the onClick event to be the same for all 3 buttons

Comment: so, do a rollback

Answer (score -1):

Instead of declaring the onClick method in the xml layout file, you could have your Fragment implement View.onClickListener interface, override `onClick()`, and set all 3 buttons onClickListener like this `btn.setOnClickListener(this)`. Put the behavior you want for all 3 buttons in `onClick()`.  All 3 will have the same behavior (unless you check which button the event came from in `onClick()`).